# Calculating spread of invasive species using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, analysis

I have ArcGIS Desktop Advanced and so far have completed the following;

1. Used Supervised classification on a satellite image to identify the invasive species with field verification. I have converted the raster to a vector polygon to get the area in hectares.
2. Used Supervised classification in a second satellite image in the same area with a different time stamp and again converted to polygon to obtain area in hectares.

I would now like to;

1. Determine the rate of spread for this current period between the 2 satellite images/polygons and;
2. Use this to predict future spread of the species.

Can anybody offer some suggestions of the workflow to use?

Comment: Solution for 1st goal is basic. Union both and check where FID of 1st and second layer equals to -1. It will show added infestation and the areas that become pests free. Second is tough, unless you have more or less the same spread (in terms of distance) around perimeter. If this is a case simple buffer around second set will do prediction